Break dependency from DMS reload/restart
We use AWS DMS to replicate (initial load + cdc) AWS Aurora MySQL data into our Redshift (in the future we are going to use ICEBERG). In case there is any issue with DMS (RI break, Task break, MySQL Major upgrade) - we recreating or restarting the task.
This force us to code in a way where we expect failures to happen, so we check at the beginning of our scripts if we are in sync, otherwise wait. Also, since there are so many updates, long SELECTs are failing on deadlocks which forces us to clone the high frequency tables.
I want to have a more elegant solution, one which we don't need to clone tables and not worry about if DMS broke or not.

If you are trying to migrate a live database, then you have to anticipate deadlocks and need to check for consistency across multiple tables. Take your app offline while migrating or use some kind of a data streaming tool to move data across.

Maybe migrate was wrong to chose, replicate is better term. The Aurora DB is our prod OLTP system. we use DMS to bring the data into the doh system for analytics and DS. it is not one time copy.

Then I would definitely look at streaming data as opposed to doing big locking selects. You should remove this question from SO and ask it on the DBA sister site as DBAs will be more experienced in cross database migrations than programmers. There are several tools developed for this purpose, but SO rules actively discourage asking for tool recommendations.

Watch traces at both the source and target. There are batch mode settings, however, that seems to only apply to the target. NETWORK_IO will be an issue with large tables.
